# Reading csv file yields different results depending if read from linux or windows host

Tags: python, csv, character-encoding

using the following code to read in a csv file I get different results depending on if I run the code on my linux host which is using Python 3.8 or on my windows machine using Python 3.6.  On the Linux host I get invalid results...

Why is this case and how do I fix it?

```
NAICS_dict_csv = {} 
with open(r'/home/mondjef/Downloads/naics-scian-2017-element-v3-eng.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == '541120':
            print(row)
        if row[3] == 'Exclusion(s)':
            exclusion = re.sub('\((?:US|CAN|MEX)\)' , '', row[4])
            NAICS_dict_csv[row[1]]['exclusions'].append(exclusion)
        elif row[3] == 'Inclusion(s)':
            NAICS_dict_csv[row[1]]['inclusions'].append(row[4])
        elif row[3] == 'Illustrative example(s)':
            NAICS_dict_csv[row[1]]['examples'].append(row[4])
        elif row[3] == 'All examples':
            NAICS_dict_csv[row[1]]['all_examples'].append(row[4])
```

on Linux machine I get:

```
['5', '541120', 'Offices of notaries', 'Illustrative example(s)', 'notary services (QuÃ²bec)']
```

on Windows machine I get:

```
['5', '541120', 'Offices of notaries', 'Illustrative example(s)', 'notary services (Québec)']
```

edit: forgot to add link to file so others can download if hey want to try to read it.
https://www.statcan.gc.ca/eng/statistical-programs/document/NAICS-SCIAN-2017-element-v3-eng.csv

Comment: Downloaded file encoding is _UTF-8-BOM_. I'd try `encoding='utf_8_sig'`. However, there is `Quòbec` instead of `Québec` inside the file…

Comment: _`name 'NAICS_dict_csv' is not defined`_. Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ how did you determine the file encoding is UTF-8-BOM?  As you noticed it does not read the file correctly as utf-8.  Additionally, there is a similar file available from the same source that is for French data...reading this file as UTF-8-BOM really makes a mess out of it as there is a lot more accented characters.

Comment: I use Notepad++ to determine a file encoding (N++ has a good guessing algorithm).  Proved by `with open(r'naics-scian-2017-element-v3-eng.csv', 'rb') as f: f.read(4)` which returns `b'\xef\xbb\xbfL'` and first three bytes are [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)…

Comment: Good to know...I guess the remaining question is why there would be any difference between reading the file on linux versus Windows using the same code